# How to see that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Definition: An operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is said to be nonnegative definite if it is self-adjoint and $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x \in H$.

Now suppose $T$ is any element of $\mathcal B(H), T^*T$ is nonnegative definite because it is self-adjoint and $\langle T^*Tx,x \rangle = ||Tx||^2$.

**Question:** How to see that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint? And how to see that  $\langle T^*Tx,x \rangle = ||Tx||^2$?

Comment: Prove that for $S,T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$, we have $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$ and $T^{**}=T$. Now apply this with $S=T^*$. For the last question, you just use the definition of the adjoint to move $T^*$ over to $x$.

Comment: Your definition is what is usually called positive, not "nonnegative definite". It does not imply definite. (Example $T=0$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval ... There are various systems of terminology.  It seems the OP is using the system that has "positive definite" for the strict inequality $>$, and "nonnegative definite" for the weak inequality $\ge$.

Comment: This seems very suspicious to me. I am used (mostly with numbers) to "positive" for $>$ and "nonnegative" for $\ge$, but what would "definite" mean with his so peculiar terminology?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to show your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned above this can be done with minimal effort. Indeed $$(T^*T)^* = T^* (T^*)^* = T^* T,$$ which shows that $T^*T$ is self adjoint. Moreover, $$\langle T^*Tx, x\rangle = \langle Tx, Tx \rangle = \|Tx\|^2.$$

Comment: I think your proof of self adjoint is not rigorous. My proof is that $<(T^* T)^* x_1, x_2> = <x_1, T^* T x_2>=<Tx_1, Tx_2>=<T^* Tx_1, x_2>$. What do you think?